# Basic primal and dual solution. Feasible? Why?

Tags: linear-programming

## Questions

[image]

---

## Attempt

I managed to solve (c) but I have trouble understanding (d) any directions would be incredibly useful.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\begin{array}{rr}
\min\quad c^Tx & \\
\text{s.t.} \quad Ax&=b \\
x &\ge 0
\end{array} & \qquad
\begin{array}{rr}
\max\quad b^Ty & \\
\text{s.t.} \; A^Ty&\le c \\
y & \text{free}
\end{array} \\
{\cal (P)} & \qquad {\cal (D)}
\end{array}
$$

The last four columns of $A$ is in the current basis.

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
2&0&0&2&1&1\\
-1&2&1&-2&2&3\\
-1&2&2&0&1&-2\\
1&-2&-1&1&0&1
\end{pmatrix},\;
B=\begin{pmatrix}
0&2&1&1\\
1&-2&2&3\\
2&0&1&-2\\
-1&1&0&1
\end{pmatrix},\\
B^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
9/5 & -1/5 & -7/5 & -4 \\
4/5 & -1/5 & -2/5 & -1 \\
-8/5 & 2/5 & 9/5 & 4 \\
1 & 0 & -1 & -2
\end{pmatrix},\;
b=\begin{pmatrix}3\\-1\\2\\0\end{pmatrix},\;
c=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 4 \\ 10 \\ 5 \\ 5 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$

The primal basic solution $x_B$ satisfies $Bx_B=b$, so

$$x_B=B^{-1}b=
\begin{pmatrix}
9/5 & -1/5 & -7/5 & -4 \\
4/5 & -1/5 & -2/5 & -1 \\
-8/5 & 2/5 & 9/5 & 4 \\
1 & 0 & -1 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}3\\-1\\2\\0\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 14/5 \\ 9/5 \\ -8/5 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

The primal basic solution is $(0,0,14/5 , 9/5 , -8/5 , 1)^T$.  By complementary slackness, the 3<sup>rd</sup>-6<sup>th</sup> dual constraints are equalities:
$B^T y = c_B := (c_3,\dots,c_6)^T$, so
$$y = (B^{-1})^T c_B
=\begin{pmatrix}
9/5  & 4/5  & -8/5 & 1 \\  
-1/5 & -1/5 & 2/5  & 0 \\
-7/5& -2/5& 9/5 & -1 \\
-4 & -1 & 4  & -2 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 10 \\ 5 \\ 5 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 14 \\ -1 \\ -7 \\ -25 \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$c^T x
= \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 4 \\ 10 \\ 5 \\ 5 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}^T
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 14/5 \\ 9/5 \\ -8/5 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = 29 \\
b^T y
= \begin{pmatrix} 3\\-1\\2\\0 \end{pmatrix}^T
\begin{pmatrix} 14 \\ -1 \\ -7 \\ -25 \end{pmatrix} = 29
$$

The corresponding dual solution is $y=(14, -1, -7, -25)^T$.
The primal basic solution not feasible as $x_5 =-8/5 < 0$.